# Current measurement on low resistance sources

Tags: current-measurement

Most of the devices to measure current at micro amps level or lower recommend a input resistance of more than 1kOhms.
(As for an example , shorting the ammeter leads, which is essentially what happens on connecting the low resistance source, produces noise in 0.5 mA range)

How do we measure current from sources which have very low resistances?

Comment: Can you give us a bigger picture idea of what you're trying to do? What is the source you're measuring? Is there any other load attached when you do the measurement? Do you want to measure the source under short-circuit conditions or some other conditions?

Comment: It is a novel method of extracting electricity from a substrate.There is no load connected to it, except the lead wires, which have comparable resistances to the substrate.
Preferably i would like to measure in the short circuit condition(no load) as addition of any load would lead to the reduction in flowing current.
In retrospect, it CAN be modeled as a current source based on plausible theory of current generation.
It is NOT a constant current source.

Comment: What do you mean by "extracting electricity"? Do you mean extracting power? Because it sounds like the basic problem is that your source isn't able to deliver any appreciable power to the meter.

Comment: No.I am trying to simply measure the current generated. It is not powering anything now

Comment: My point is, it isn't able to power anything, and that is the reason you can't measure it. If you have a ("novel") way to extract energy from this system, then you know much more than us about it and you should use some form of that method to make your measurement.

Answer (score 1):

One way to measure very low resistances is to pass a relatively large current through the device under test (DUT), with a Kelvin (4-wire) connection. Then a precision amplifier can be used to measure the voltage drop.

[image: http://img.deusm.com/designnews/2013/10/269248/1-fig-1.jpg]

For example, suppose you have a 1A current source and an amplifier with 10mV full scale input (and say a 3-1/2 digit ADC). Then you can measure with 5\$\mu\Omega\$ resolution.

It may be better to use +/-1A alternating and make alternate +/- measurements in order to get rid of thermoelectric voltages, but that's a detail.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, my question is to measure current.
Thank you

Comment: I suggest controlling current and measuring voltage.

Answer (score 1):

If an active circuit is OK, then you can use a TIA (Trans-impedance amp) to measure low currents with no burden resistor.  (Currents are typically returned to ground.)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier

Measuring current from a photodiode in the above, but current can be from any source.

Comment: Hi, i am guessing the electrometre used features one of these.The problem is photodiodes also come under the family of semiconductors, which even under activated conditions have high resistances.
This would probably be more than the required minimum resistance.

Comment: FYI
http://s15.postimg.org/4njl9tp23/abc.png
http://s24.postimg.org/t5olhvll1/abc.png

Comment: Can you simply average longer to overcome the increased noise?

Comment: @lakki Sorry I'm confused what you are trying to do?  The TIA certainly has noise gain (opamp voltage noise amplified by feed back R and capacitance at inverting input.)